# OpenCV C++ Error with sinusoidal pattern generation - structured_light library

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv-contrib

I am trying to use the sinusoidal pattern tool in C++ with Visual Studio. I have placed the code that I am testing this with below. In visual studio everything looks fine bar the red squiggle under params in the following line:

```
Ptr<structured_light::SinusoidalPattern> sinus = structured_light::SinusoidalPattern::create(params);
```

When I try to build I get the following error message:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error (active)        
no suitable user-defined conversion from 
"cv::structured_light::SinusoidalPattern::Params" to 
"cv::Ptr<cv::structured_light::SinusoidalPattern::Params>" exists   Structured_Light_Test   
c:\Users\ianco\Desktop\CPlusPlus_Programming\Structured_Light_Test\Structured_Light_Test\Main.cpp   70
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could offer some advice on how I could get round this issue or suggest another method.

CODE:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/structured_light.hpp>
#include <opencv2/phase_unwrapping.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    structured_light::SinusoidalPattern::Params params;
    params.width = 1080;
    params.height = 700;
    params.nbrOfPeriods = 5;
    params.setMarkers = true;
    params.horizontal = false;
    params.methodId = 2;
    params.shiftValue = static_cast<float>(2 * CV_PI / 3);
    params.nbrOfPixelsBetweenMarkers = 70;
    String outputPatternPath = "C:/Users/ianco/Desktop/CPlusPlus_Programming";
    String outputWrappedPhasePath = "C:/Users/ianco/Desktop/CPlusPlus_Programming";
    String outputUnwrappedPhasePath = "C:/Users/ianco/Desktop/CPlusPlus_Programming";

    Ptr<structured_light::SinusoidalPattern> sinus = structured_light::SinusoidalPattern::create(params);
    // Storage for patterns
    vector<Mat> patterns;
    //Generate sinusoidal patterns
    sinus->generate(patterns);


    cv::Mat blue, green, red;
    std::vector<cv::Mat> images(3);

    // OpenCV works natively with BGR ordering
    images.at(0) = patterns[0];
    images.at(1) = patterns[1];
    images.at(2) = patterns[2];

    cv::Mat color;
    cv::merge(images, color);

    namedWindow("pattern", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    setWindowProperty("pattern", WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
    imshow("pattern", color);
    waitKey(3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d6/d96/classcv_1_1structured__light_1_1SinusoidalPattern.html#a97045af313f2fa0fa68b12734cf48320) tells you that `params` should also be a Ptr but you passed the object...

try using [makePtr](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/dc/d84/group__core__basic.html#ga94b059075f41314c83dd2a2758c81acd)

Change this line:

```
structured_light::SinusoidalPattern::Params params;
```

with this:

```
Ptr<cv::structured_light::SinusoidalPattern::Params> params = makePtr< SinusoidalPattern::Params >();
```

you will have to change `.` to `->` for each use of params like `params.width = 1080;` would be `params->width = 1080;`, since it will be a pointer now.

The rest of the code should be ok.

Comment: @IanCoghill can you provide me the link to this tutorial?, just as a small test, does it compiles without passing the params? which version of OpenCV are you using? maybe they change the function... does the error change? or is the same? just in case, I was talking about changing this line `structured_light::SinusoidalPattern::Params params;`

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am still getting errors. I took this piece of code from the OpenCV Sinusoidal Pattern tutorial:
"https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d0/de8/tutorial_capture_sinusoidal_pattern.html" 
Even trying the full code provided there comes up with the same error.

My changes resulted in the following:
     `Ptr<cv::structured_light::SinusoidalPattern::Params> sinus = makePtr< cv::structured_light::SinusoidalPattern::Params >();
 // Storage for patterns
 vector<Mat> patterns;
 //Generate sinusoidal patterns
 sinus->generate(patterns);
`
Error: class has no member "generate"

Comment: It worked, I am sorry I misunderstood. Thanks very much again.

Comment: @IanCoghill good to here that, I edited the question to make it more clear for the next reader :)